# Why won't my IF-ELSE-IF statement work correctly?

Tags: java, if-statement, java-8, blackjack

I am trying to create a simple Blackjack game in Java. I have a menu with possible integer options from 1-4. If the user inputs an integer greater than 4, my IF statement needs to print "invalid integer" and then restart the game. If the user inputs a negative value, my ELSE-IF statement needs to do the same thing.

However, the statements will only work once, so I can't get "invalid integer" to print if I input values below 0 and values greater than 4 multiple times/back-to-back.

[Redacted]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is the condition for dealing with an input greater than 4? I’m not seeing it.

Comment: You use `continue;` statements which implies that there is a loop around your statements. Where is this loop? I can't see it...

Comment: The default statement is for any input that isn't 1-4. The statements are all within one while loop that plays successive games so long as the user input isn't 4 (if the user input is 4, the while loop breaks and the game stops).

Comment: You need to put the logic inside a loop so that it will keep looping until you get have a correct answer. There are many questions here that discuss this.

Comment: Side note: your `switch (chosen)` for the cases 2 - 10 is entirely obsolete. All cases are doing the same, only differing in the printed message which can be rewritten as simple as: `if(chosen >= 2 && chosen <= 10) { System.out.println("Your card is a " + chosen + "!"); playerHand = playerHand + chosen; System.out.println("Your hand is: " + playerHand); }` And you should place the check for reaching 21 after the first if statements, to always check it, not only when a King has been chosen. Then, you wouldn’t need to repeat the “Your hand is” print statements either.

Comment: Did you try searching for the words ___java blackjack game console___ to see how other people have done it? For example, here's one from the _Code Review_ site: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/174797/simple-blackjack-game-in-console/174821

Answer (score 1):

If you have defined scnr like this:

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
```

I suggest you do a simple switch case statement with a default clause.

```
switch (userOpt) {
    case 1:
        // Option 1 logic...
    case 2:
        // Option 2 logic...
    case 3:
        // Option 3 logic...           
    case 4:
        // Option 4 logic...
    default:
        // Handling invalid input...
}
```

Comment: I just did that, but now the logic inside each case won't run at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's really confusing in the way you've written the code.
I.e how does case 1 involve get another card?
Is all the code written in a main function? How about you make a class called blackjack in which you have different methods for getCard(), holdHand() etc. and make a class variable which holds the hand and also gamecount and wins for dealer/player. Would be much easier to understand your code.
Then you can try you code in your main inside the code.

Something like;

```
public BlackJack { 
**class variables such as hand, player wins etc..**

**methods here**

**main method to try your code**
}
```

I hope you get what I'm suggesting, I know it might feel like a lot of work to do now when you've written your code but this would help you and anyone who reads your code.